# C++ type deduction for static factory method

Tags: c++, c++17, type-deduction

Since C++17 it is now much easier to instantiate a class that has many template parameters that can be automatically deduced from the constructor call.

In my project I have a hierarchy of template classes that can be nested one in another which leads to enormous type-names, which is a reason why the class template argument deduction is so nice.

However, I use also static factory methods to ease the dynamic construction of the classes (basically I just return shared_ptrs containing the newly created object). Just like in the example below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct S {
    const std::shared_ptr<T> m_t;
    S(std::shared_ptr<T> t):
        m_t {std::move(t)} {}

    template<typename ...Args>
    static S create(Args&&... args);
};

template <typename T>
template <typename ...Args>
std::shared_ptr<S<T>> S<T>::create(Args&&... args) {
    return std::make_shared<S<T>>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}




int main() {
    auto s1 = S{std::make_shared<int>(6)};
    // auto s2 = S::create(std::make_shared<int>(5));   // DOESN'T work
}
```

I need the pointers to enable polymorphism (unless there is another way that doesn't need pointers - CRTP, maybe) but I see no way to make the instantiation process easy, without the burden of specifying the full type of the returned object somewhere.

Comment: Does `create` need to be a class member? Would a free function or a wrapping class be acceptable?

Comment: Anything is ok if it allows me to omit the template parameters.

Comment: Is there a reason `create` accepts more than one parameter, if the constructor of `S` does accept only one?

Comment: Yes, this is just a silly example, my classes use more parameters.

Comment: s1 and the return type of create are S<T>, not shared_ptr<S<T>> as in @eukaryota's answer, and as the text might lead us to believe. Which did you intend?

Comment: Sorry, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename ...Args>
auto createS(Args&&... args) {
    return std::make_shared<decltype(S{std::forward<Args>(args)...})>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    auto s1 = S{std::make_shared<int>(6)};
    auto s2 = createS(std::make_shared<int>(5));
}
```

This should make sure that the type is deduced exactly the same way as for `s1`.

In fact you can generalize this to do any class template argument deduction:

```
template <template<typename...> class Tmpl, typename ...Args>
auto make_shared_deduced(Args&&... args) {
    return std::make_shared<decltype(Tmpl{std::forward<Args>(args)...})>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    auto s1 = S{std::make_shared<int>(6)};
    auto s2 = make_shared_deduced<S>(std::make_shared<int>(5));
}
```

See also [standard proposal P1069R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1069r0.html).

Whether you really want all these `shared_ptr` I don't know. Probably they should only be used at very specific instances, not generally like this.

Comment: Well, sadly your answer highlighted to me that my question (and my code design) is just bad and I need to change it. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @A.Budziak I generalized the answer a bit. I am not sure whether your design is good or not, I was just mentioning that one has to be careful with `shared_ptr` (because of performance and also possible memory leaks due to circular dependencies).

Comment: Oh, the generalization is really nice.

I'm aware of the risks regarding shared_ptrs but the structure is actually tree-like, so it is not a problem here, I hope.